# Python writing to file and json returns None/null instead of value

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi, cgi

I'm trying to write data to a file with the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/python37all
print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
import cgi
from Alarm import *
import json

htmldata = cgi.FieldStorage()
alarm_time = htmldata.getvalue('alarm_time')
alarm_date = htmldata.getvalue('alarm_date')
print(alarm_time,alarm_date)
data = {'time':alarm_time,'date':alarm_date}
# print(data['time'],data['date'])

with open('alarm_data.txt','w') as f:
    json.dump(data,f)
...
```

but when opening the the file, I get the following output:
`{'time':null,'date':null}`

The print statement returns what I except it to: `14:26 2020-12-12`.
I've tried this same method with `f.write()` but it returns both values as `None`. This is being run on a raspberry pi. Why aren't the correct values being written?

--EDIT--
The json string I expect to see is the following:`{'time':'14:26','date':'2020-12-12'}`

Comment: Please update your question with the exact json string you expect to see in your file.

Comment: updated the question. Thank you

Comment: Ok, part of the problem is that what you are expecting is not actually ‘json’, so json.dump() cannot produce it. Did you mean: data = {'time':str(alarm_time), 'date':str(alarm_date)} ?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. That is what I meant. getvalue() returns the data as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant:

```py
data = {'time':str(alarm_time), 'date':str(alarm_date)}
```

I would expect to see your file contents like this:

```json
{"time":"14:26","date":"2020-12-12"}
```

Note the double quotes: `"`. `json` is very strict about these things, so don't fool yourself into having single quotes `'` in a file and expecting `json` to parse it.

Comment: I made this edit, but I'm still getting the script still outputs null's in the file.

Comment: What happens if you add `print(data)` just before `json.dump(data,f)`?

Comment: The screen shows the output that I want `{'time': '15:18', 'date': '2020-12-12'}`, but when I go into the file the output is `{'time': null, 'date': null}`

Comment: Just be careful here! As I've already said, if you're seeing: `'time'` etc you are not seeing `json` and the `json` module could not have produced such a thing.

Comment: You're completely right, in the file I'm seeing `{"time": null, "date": null}`

Comment: Ok, I tried: `data = {'time': '15:18', 'date': '2020-12-12'};  json.dump(data,f)` and my file has: `{"time": "15:18", "date": "2020-12-12"}`. You must be looking in a different file.

Comment: My `alarm_data.txt` is the only `.txt` file in the directory. Even when I clear the contents of `alarm.txt` and run it again, same output writes to the file `{"time": null, "date": null}`

Comment: Try changing the filename. Also you don't show all your code, so is there another part which uses this `open()` or is there another `open()` somewhere else?

Comment: I changed the file name and I'm now getting this output from the new file: `{"time":"None","date","None"}`. The rest of the code is a bunch of `print()` statements which create the webpage. The part I posted is the only code that concerns opening and writing to a file.

Comment: Ok, well, now that you have: `"None"`, this means that: `htmldata.getvalue('alarm_date')` is returning `None`, which is why you had `null` before.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm confused why my `print(alarm_time,alarm_date)` statement returns the correct values?

Comment: Well, I suggest you do: `print(data)` just after creating `data` and also just before writing to the file. There is something else going on that creates this confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You were right when you said it has something to do with the `html.getvalue()` line. There must be some sort of error with the data type, because when I used the line `data = {"time":alarm_time[:],"date":alarm_data[:]}` I get the correct output. I appreciate it!